# XML RPC Header Modification with JAVA

Tags: java

I need to add the authentication while sending xml-rpc request. 
POST /Air HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 1704
Content-Type: text/xml
User-Agent: UGw Server/5.0/1.0
Host: localhost 
Authorization: Basic ZmRzdXNlcjpmZHN1c2Vy

But not able to find how to do it.

This is how I am sending the request in JAVA

```
XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
config.setServerURL(new URL("http://localhost:8088/RPC2"));
config.setUserAgent("UGw Server/5.0/1.0");

XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();

client.setConfig(config);

Integer result = (Integer)client.execute("translate.sum", params);
```